# How to disable/disconnect ethernet adapter in mac os x programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, macos, operating-system

I am new to mac os x programming and just got an assignment to write small utility that disable either wireless or wired adapter based on configuration. I was able to disconnect wireless using corewlan framework like :

```
CWInterface interface = [CWInterface interfaceWithName:@"en1"];
BOOL result = [interface setPower:NO error:&err];
```

and it is working as expected. I need similar code to disable/disconnect ethernet adapter. I researched that ifconfig (as mentioned below can be used):

```
sudo ifconfig en0 down
```

but it require admin password and that i don't want to do. Please suggest an alternative programatic way to disable ethernet adapter without root password.

I read that **SCNetworkConfiguration** can be used but don't know how to use it. Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Here is an Alternative command (sadly, even this requires admin password).

`networksetup -setnetworkserviceenabled Ethernet on`

 I got it from here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/networksetup.8.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot shut off network interfaces without having admin access (i.e. that's why the padlock is there in the Network Preference Pane).  Think of it this way... you would not want non-admin users on any public machine being able to turn off the network arbitrarily.

For my own apps where I also disable Ethernet & WiFi, I have to get privileges to launch a separate tool in order to run stuff from the SystemConfiguration framework as admin.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So here comes two more question now: 1) Does apple approve such apps those need root user password? (i afraid so) 2) Any example to run code in privilege way (the way apple accept) would be great help to me. Like run via SystemConfiguration frmework as admin.

Comment: Answer to question # 1 is "no", because it sounds like you want to get this app up on the Apple App Store, and with [Sandboxing](http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/mac/app-sandbox/) being a requirement you can not do any admin-priviledged anything. Look at the [Determine Whether Your App Is Suitable for Sandboxing section](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/DesigningYourSandbox/DesigningYourSandbox.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011183-CH4-SW6). For my own app, I will be looking into using ipfw, which may be okay for user-level apps.

Comment: Thanks so much for the clarification. Appreciated your help.